# How can i stop rendering Qgis

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, rendering

In my python plugin ,i select features from a vector layer dynamically using a loop and executing :
    VectorLayer.select(feature.id())

when i start the loop, the selection become very slow because the rendering .
can i suspend and reactivate  rendering in qgis programatically in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your code this is generally the wrong way to do this.  You should use `QgsVectorLayer::setSelectedFeatures` to select features in one go.

```
ids = [feature.id() for feature in forselection]
layer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
```

or with some long loop:

```
   ifs = []
   for feature in process:
       ..... #do some other stuff
       ids.append(feature.id())

   layer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
```

Comment: this work in QGis api 1.8 ?

Comment: Yes it will.  That method has been there for a while.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as accepted.